# AngularFire getting the index value in html

Tags: firebase, angularfire

The Firebase documentation says to structure data like this:

> "members": {
>           "mchen": true,
>           "hmadi": true
>        }

I now what to use the keys in my HTML. I know I can simply create a variable in javascript but I am wondering if I can simply right something like this.

```
<li ng-repeat="member in members">
    <a ui-sref="new-page({id:'{{member.SOMETHING}}'})">{{ member.SOMETHING }}</a>
</li>
```

In the code above with what should I replace `SOMETHING` be to print `mchen` and `hmadi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `$id` and `$value` for that:

```
<li ng-repeat="member in members">
    <a ui-sref="new-page({id:'{{member.$id}}'})">{{ member.$value }}</a>
</li>
```

`$id` exists on any AngularFire object that you use in `ng-repeat`. `$value` only exists when the object is a primitive type (here it's a boolean).

See the section of the [AngularFire docs on meta fields on an object](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html#section-meta-fields).